# Embed FontDialog in another WinForms Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I would like to embed the FontDialog control into a settings dialog box for my C# WinForms application, but if I drag the control over it, of course, just adds it to the list of Dialog controls at the bottom of the designer.  But instead of opening a separate dialog, I would like it to just be part of the settings dialog I already have...so I don't have to recreate the whole thing.

Is there anyway to do this, or is there another Font control I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a long shot, but have a look a [Windows Live Writer](http://writer.live.com/). It's a free app from Microsoft that's written in managed code. It has an "insert picture" dialog that embeds the OpenFileDialog onto another WinForms dialog.

You can use reflector to see how they did it. I bet the the technique they're using will work for the FontDialog as well.

Comment: Unfortunately that link has gone dead. The following link currently (June 2018) works: https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8621